# SQL Self Join / Pivot table query

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, pivot-table, self-join

I have the following Table1 in SQL Server 2016:

```
SELECT Year, Type, Value From Table1

    Year  Type  Value
    2010  1     10
    2010  2     15
    2010  3     20
    2011  1     100
    2011  2     150
    2011  3     200
```

I would like to convert it to the following table:

```
Year  Type1  Type2  Type3
2010  10     15     20
2011  100    150    200
```

I think we can do either self join or pivot table to achieve this. What is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: Have you try any of those? both will work. self join is easy to implement if only a few types. but conditional aggregation would work better. Pivot if you have many types or not sure which one you will have and can write a dynamic pivot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE #myTable (
[Year] int, [Type] int, [Value] int, [ExtraColumn] varchar(10));

INSERT INTO #myTable ([Year], [Type], [Value], [ExtraColumn]) 
VALUES (2010, 1, 10, 'I'), 
       (2010, 2, 15, 'G'), 
       (2010, 3, 20, 'N'), 
       (2011, 1, 100, 'O'), 
       (2011, 2, 150, 'R'), 
       (2011, 3, 200, 'E'); 

select Year, [1] as Type1, [2] as Type2, [3] as Type3 
from ( 
 select [Year], [Type], [Value] 
 from #myTable 
 ) t 
PIVOT ( SUM(Value) FOR [Type] IN ( [1], [2], [3] ) ) pvt;

-- OR
with myData as
( 
 select [Year], [Type], [Value] 
 from #myTable 
)
select Year, [1] as Type1, [2] as Type2, [3] as Type3 
from myData
PIVOT ( SUM(Value) FOR [Type] IN ( [1], [2], [3] ) ) pvt;

drop table #myTable;
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you always have 3 types using conditional aggregation is a simple way to tackle this.

```
select [Year]
    , Type1 = Max(case when [Type] = 1 then Value end)
    , Type2 = Max(case when [Type] = 2 then Value end)
    , Type3 = Max(case when [Type] = 3 then Value end)
from Table1
group by [Year]
order by [Year]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select * 
from myTable PIVOT ( SUM(Value) FOR [Type] IN ( [1], [2], [3] ) ) pvt;
```

[DbFiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=4b1f30ede9c2a388dfcd90ede59f8891)

Comment: I have some extra columns in "myTable". How can I ignore them? they somehow impact the final output even if I don't use them.

Comment: @developer, You can list the columns you want instead of using a * (and actually that is the recommended way, I was lazy).

Comment: Created table with extra column CREATE TABLE #myTable
    ([Year] int, [Type] int, [Value] int, [ExtraColumn] varchar(10)). Insert script: INSERT INTO #myTable
    ([Year], [Type], [Value], [ExtraColumn])
VALUES
    (2010, 1, 10, 'I'),
    (2010, 2, 15, 'G'),
    (2010, 3, 20, 'N'),
    (2011, 1, 100, 'O'),
    (2011, 2, 150, 'R'),
    (2011, 3, 200, 'E');  Select query: select Year, [1] as Type1, [2] as Type2, [3] as Type3
from #myTable PIVOT ( SUM(Value) FOR [Type] IN ( [1], [2], [3] ) ) pvt. Somehow it does not show correct result.

Comment: @developer, adding as another answer for not to clutter here.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you always have 3 types, you can use PIVOT in SQL.

Here is an example based on your example:

```
if object_id('tempdb..#temp1') is not null
    drop table #temp1

create table #temp1 (
     Year  int
     ,Type  int
     ,Value int
)

insert into #temp1 values 
    (2010,1,10),
    (2010,2,15),
    (2010,3,20),
    (2011,1,100),
    (2011,2,150),
    (2011,3,200)

SELECT 
    Year
    , [1] AS Type1
    , [2] AS Type2
    , [3] AS Type3
FROM   
    #temp1 p  
PIVOT  
(  
sum(value)  
FOR type IN  
( [1], [2], [3])  
) AS pvt  
ORDER BY pvt.Year
```

Here are the results:

[image: Pivot Results]